# virtualbox's copy and paste between host and base not working

Tags: virtualbox, copy

I am using virtual box on ubuntu 16.04 but I am not able copy-paste between my base machine Ubuntu and vm Kali.
Based on suggestion I have tried below commands:
I have enabled by bidirectional shared clipboard
I have installed virtualbox-guest-x11,virtualbox-guest-dkms.
I have executed the command service virtualbox-guest-utils start

Comment: I don't think that copy/paste between host and vm have ever worked.

Comment: Copy and paste between my Ubuntu host and any of numerous guest machines works fine. @siddhu619 Have you installed Guest Additions?

Comment: @heynnema Why say that, I use it all the time!

Comment: @George I'll have to retry it. In the past, it has never worked for me.

Comment: Siddhu619, did you add it to the guest OS from the option `Insert Guest Additions CD Image`

Comment: @heynnema After adding to host you have to add it again in the guest.

Comment: @George I just rechecked, and clipboard and drag-and-drop don't work for me. Bi-directional is enabled in the settings. I don't understand what you mean by "adding to host you have to add it again in the guest".

Comment: @George I just rechecked settings, and in the guest, and they're both enabled bi-directional.

Comment: Yes @heynnema when you launch the guest look at the menu at the top and you will see `device` same place where you will find `shared clipboard` it's the last entry there. Click on it and it will launch a terminal in the guest and install the needed. If debian you may have to do it manually from terminal after you navigate there.

Comment: @George my host is Ubuntu GNOME. My guest that I'm testing this on is also Ubuntu GNOME. I see the Device menu and the shared clipboard item, but bi-directional is already enabled, and selecting it again does nothing, and if I select disable, and then bi-directional again, still nothing happens. Doesn't the Device menu get its clipboard and D&D from the main VM settings? They're all enabled.

Comment: Look for `Insert Guest Additions CD Image` its at the bottom of where `shared clipboard` is... click on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63375/discussion-between-george-and-heynnema).

Comment: oh, you meant for me to install Guest Additions! They were already installed, but I upgraded them, rebooted the guest, and clipboard and D&D still don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try [this answer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031897/ubuntu-lxde-18-04-and-16-04-virtualbox-bidirectional-clipboard-sharing-not-worki) Specifically, after guest additions installed, open a terminal and type this:

```
sudo VBoxClient --clipboard
```

after that it should work even after reboot.

Comment: Fantastic this worked