# How to enable copy-and-paste of a Ubuntu VirtualMachine running on MacOS host?

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox

I am running a VirtualMachine (6.0.14) on MacOS 14.10.6, with Ubuntu 20.04 installed in the VM. I think I have installed the Guest Additions, and under `Settings -> General -> Advanced` I did select `Bidirectional` for `Shared Clipboard` and `Drag'n'Drop`.

However, when I copy some text in the host system (MacOS) by using CTRL-C or mouse right click -> copy, I am not able to paste that text into the Terminal on the client system (Ubuntu) running in the Virtualbox (neither right-mouse click is working, nor CTRL-V).

I also tried to run (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943177/virtualboxs-copy-and-paste-between-host-and-base-not-working?rq=1)):

```
sudo VBoxClient --clipboard
```

but this did not solve my problem.

The kernel module seems to be loaded, as I get some output from this command

```
lsmod | grep vboxguest
```

So what else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there was a bug with version 6.0.14 of VirtualBox.
Upgrading to 6.1.22 did solve this problem.

Now I can either paste with right-mouse click or with `CTRL-Shift-V`.

Comment: thanks for finding this but, aehm bug ! ;-)